# Unable to findElement by css for an element with multiple classnames

Tags: selenium, xpath

In my webdriver test I have a web page with a tag named `c-wiz` with the  `class="boqChromeogbviewView_ boqChromeapiViewView_ modeChromeScrollable_"`. I need to send an <kbd>ESC</kbd> key press to this element since it has a listener for it. So I tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//c- 
    wiz[@class='boqChromeogbviewView_']")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```

but it fails saying

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//c-wiz[@class='boqChromeogbviewView_']"}

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

With xpath you have to use whole class value or use `contains` like below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//c- 
    wiz[@class='boqChromeogbviewView_ boqChromeapiViewView_ modeChromeScrollable_']")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//c- 
        wiz[contains(@class,'boqChromeogbviewView_']")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```

Use css selector instead:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("c- 
    wiz.boqChromeogbviewView_")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```